# how to send send a message in remote machine

Tags: batch-file, cmd

if I am using the following command command `msg * /server:127.0.0.1 Hello world`

then it opens pop box and displays Hello world

If I use the similar way to send a message to remote system

`msg * /server:192.168.1.56 Hello world` then it shows

```
Error 5 getting session names
```

whats the reason behind and how to send message to remote machine

remote os can either be windows 7 or windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

Not since Windows XP.  It's a security flaw.

`msg` send messages to terminal sessions on terminal server. Workstations are limited terminal servers, limited to one interactive user, so `msg` works on local computers.

Anything you can do remotely is always invisible to the user on the remote computer.

You can send a ***program*** to display a message using psexec by MS though, its not part of windows. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545027.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to do it and the method you described should work.

I recently attempted to do this exact operation but I was blocked because if user rights on the PC's and the only way to make this function available was to edit the reg. You will continue to get that error until the Reg on both computers has been edited to allow the messages. Now if you are not on your own computer and you do have system administrators they could have blocked these functions for security purposes. If you want to attempt to edit the registry to allow you to do this you need to follow these instructions

1. Open the Registry Editor ( regedit.exe ).
2. In the left panel, locate and then click on the following registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server
3. In the right panel, find the key AllowRemoteRPC and be sure the value of the key is 1. If the value is not 1, change it to 1.
4. Close Registry Editor and restart your computer.
5. Run MSG.EXE command in the elevated CMD window. Launch it when you hold Ctrl+Shift keys to enter elevated mode.

http://www.cezeo.com/tips-and-tricks/msg-command/

If you run into admin rights errors you will either need to contact the server admins or you will need to find a different way to talk to people in your office :P I recommend gmails messaging system for that. You can log into mail.google.com then click their email address on the bottom left and send them instant messages. As long as they have google up as well or set up email notifications to their phone they can communicate back with you.